# fetching master table data, getting error

Tags: sql-server

i want to get text values from a master table corresponding to a string (which is comma seperated string of master table userid column) stored in another table

i am trying as

```
select maritialtype from tblmastermaritialstatus where MaritalStatusId in(select MaritalStatusId from tblPartnerBasicDetail where userid=1)
```

`maritalstatusid` in `tblPartnerBasicDetail` is a string like `1,2,3`

i am getting error

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value '1,2,3' to data type tinyint.

how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Comma seperated nvarchar data is not the same as comma seperated integers.

You are doing something similar to:

```
WHERE 1 IN ("1,2,3")
```

`1` is an `integer`, `"1,2,3"` is a `string` (which cannot be implicitly converted). Therefore you are getting an error.

I would recommend normalising your data so that there is no need for comma seperated values.

In the long run this will save you a lot of issues.

---

However, if you wish to stick with CSV, you may find this article helpful:

http://www.nigelrivett.net/SQLTsql/InCsvStringParameter.html

Check the `fn_ParseCSVString` part specifically

Comment: but i stored group of selected ids in comma seperated form so that searching would be easier using 'SELECT something FROM table WHERE somevalues IN (that group)'. m i doing wrong by storing values this way in database

Comment: Yes you'll always run into problems comma seperating values in a database. It's best to make another table related to the one with the 3 comma seperated values, and have 1 record for each.

Comment: but there must be some conversion or something which can resolve it rather than seperating tables

Comment: In the long run normalising the data will save you a lot of issues, however I've updated my answer with a CSV solution link.